# RFC P&G GET URL JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, get

Good afternoon, I have the following problem, I use AJAX to URL requests, the problem is that when I pass an RFC that has among its characters one & only get chain & this before.

Example:

```
Http://......../Get?RFCRec=P&G5609219R2
```

this is fine, but when the request arrives, I just get the letter P.
I think I can parse to the request string.

My code is:

```
        GetT: function (item) {
        //alert(item.value);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Get + "?RfcRec=" + item.value,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#Receptor-Rfc").bind('change', function () {
                    alrdocument.clearTaxPayerReceiverId();
                });
            }
        })
    },
```

some suggestions????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `encodeURIComponent(item.value)`.  Ampersand & is a special character in URLS that separates multiple query parameters.  Your request is being misinterpreted as including two different parameter names: `RFCRec` whose value is 'P' and `G5609219R2` whose value is empty.

A generic example of a URL that includes multiple query parameters:

```
http://example.com/index.html?a=5&b=7&c=9
```

This URL contains three parameters, a, b, and c.  The ampersand acts as a separator.

Comment: Thanks I had already tried something similar, a variable created before and that is the concatenated to the URL. But again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You can replace "&" for "%26"

```
 url: Get + "?RfcRec=" + item.value.replace('&','%26')
```